# popup always open in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to open a new tab all the time when the user clicks it. But currently in my implementation all the time the single new tab is refreshed.

Here is my code

```
<a target="_new" href="http://mylink" class="personallink"><img src="myimage.png" alt="Personal"></a>
```

How to always create a new tab on click of it?

Comment: `target="_new"` -> `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<a target="_new" href="http://mylink" class="personallink"><img src="myimage.png" alt="Personal"></a>
```

Use

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mylink" class="personallink"><img src="myimage.png" alt="Personal"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mylink">My Link</a>
```